# Print margins not appearing correctly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried editing the Print Margin Column option in General->Editors->Text Editors in Eclipse, but the margin line is still showing at 120 characters. I have heard that you need to go to Java->Code Style->Formatter, but the Code Style option is not available under the Java tab in preferences.

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this? Current versions should have the Code Style entry.

Answer (score 1):

Go there **Preferences** -> **C/C++** -> **Formatter** -> **New** -> Enter name -> Now in Formatter window click **Edit** -> choose tab **Line Wrapping**

You must create new profile because existing profiles are built-in.